# HP system health SNMP branch not available on Linux

Tags: centos, hp, snmp

I'm running an HP system with CentOS 7.

The SNMP info about the HDD health was not available.  For example, the [check_hp](https://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Hardware/Server-Hardware/HP-(Compaq)/check_hp/details) Nagios/Icinga plugin by Guenther Mair reports `Compaq/HP Agent Check:  no cpq/hp component found`.  (Test by running **`/usr/local/lib/nagios/plugins/check_hp`**.)

/var/log/hp-snmp-agents/cma.log showed that several daemons had aborted.  It turns out cmahealthd not running and this was why the SNMP MIB for HDDs was missing.

Restarting the systemd service didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled the packages and this fixed the issue:

```
sudo yum erase hp-health
sudo yum install hp-health hp-snmp-agents
```